# Weird things happened when programming in c++20 with fmodules-ts

Tags: c++, linux, c++20

I have two source files: `main.cxx` and `env.cxx`. And `main.cxx` depends on `env.cxx`

If I compile them with
`c++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -Wall -g env.cxx main.cxx`, then everything works well.

But if I compile them with

```
c++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -Wall -g -c env.cxx
c++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -Wall -g -c main.cxx
c++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -Wall -g env.o main.o
```

I get segmentation fault.

I do not know whether it is a gcc bug or not, because it works well again if I **rewrite them in c++17 style**, removing the module declarations.

My compiler is gcc 11.1.0 (The newest version up to now)

Here is env.cxx:

```
module;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <stdexcept>
export module env;

export namespace env
{

std::string get_env(const char* name)
{
    char* p = ::getenv(name);
    if (p == nullptr)
        throw std::runtime_error("environment variable not found");
    return std::string(p);
}

// These two functions are useless this time.
std::string get_env(const std::string& name)
{
    return get_env(name.data());
}

std::string get_env(std::string_view name)
{
    std::string s{name};
    return get_env(s.data());
}

}
```

And main.cxx

```
module;
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
import env;
export module main;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::cout << env::get_env("HOME") << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Can you reproduce this?

---

Update 2021.06-19 15:44

In fact the two compiling commands above both work well, and the way that produces segfault is actually:

```
c++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -Wall -g -c env.cxx
c++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -Wall -g -c main.cxx
c++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -Wall -g main.o env.o
```

Note that the place of `main.o` and `env.o` has been changed.

Comment: When you run the failing program in a debugger, on what line is the segfault and what is the nature of the segfault, e.g. is it a null pointer dereference or a wild/invalid pointer or something else obvious?

Comment: Your code and compilation methods both work fine for me with no problems: `c++ (GCC) 11.1.1 20210531 (Red Hat 11.1.1-3)`

Comment: can't reproduce with gcc 11.1.0 linux, but this version ICEs out with e.g. -fsanitize=undefined  -fmodules-ts so not too reliable.